# Windows Builder in Eclipse Juno - cluttered palette

Tags: eclipse

Installed Windows Builder in Eclipse Juno from google repo (plugin for eclipse 4.2, beta and stable), but the palette window is cluttered, it's "stuck" in upper left corner of Eclipse an d partly overwritten by project explorer, menus and buttons that are overlapping. Not usable.

Any solution to this? Revert to Eclipse 3.7?

Comment: Blind guess: try preferences->general->appearance->classic. Restart eclipse.

Comment: Didn't quite do the trick ...

Comment: running on Ubuntu, I should add ...

Comment: Another blind guess: Close Eclipse and try renaming `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi` in your workspace before a restart. This will reset your workbench preferences, but Eclipse might be able to create a correct layout from scratch.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have any luck with that.